# Store values of a variable in a list for some condition in Stata

Tags: list, stata

I have a dummy variable that equals 1 for some of my observations that are of interest. I want to create a list with all of the values (strings) of a particular variable when this dummy is 1. However, I have some issues getting `levelsof` to work.

I'm trying to create a new dummy equal to 1 if another variable equals any of the values stored in the local.

```
    levelsof var1 if ridccp == 1, local(cm)
    gen test=1 if var2 == "`cm'"
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that `levelsof` worked as intended, although we can't be certain in the absence of a reproducible example.

The "issue" is how to use the local macro.

The local macro contains a copy of each (all) of the distinct values in the variable fed to `levelsof`.

Something like this may thus be closer to what you want after the `levelsof` command.

```
gen test = 0 

foreach word of local cm { 
     replace test = 1 if var2 == "`word'"
}
```

but that is a sketch that takes no account of spaces or quotation marks within the distinct string values.

(0, 1) dummy variables (much better called "indicator variables") are much more useful than (1, .) variables. See also https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/1536867X19830921

Comment: Thank you for input. Actually, what I want to do is to store all the values in the local in a new list like this where a new dummy is created if another variable equals the list
`levelsof clearingmemberid if ridccp == 1 | oidccp == 1, local(cm)
 
inlist2 repcpid, val(cm) name(ridcm)`

however I'm getting error messages.

Comment: You're getting error messages because `inlist2` wants a comma-separated list of valies, not the name of a local macro.  Again, you're not giving a reproducible example, so helping you is hard. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for how to do that.

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it as you suggested above with this code, thx!

`levelsof clearingmemberid if ridccp == 1 | oidccp == 1, local(cm)
 gen ridcm = 0
 gen oidcm = 0
 foreach value of local cm {
  replace ridcm = 1 if repcpid == "value"
  replace oidcm = 1 if othcpid == "value"
 }`